# Different execution speed with idle vs heavy-load CPU

Tags: macos, performance, emulation

Fellow colleagues,

I'm currently working on a PowerPC emulator written in C++. In order to evaluate its performance, I'm using std::chrono:high_resolution_clock to measure execution time of a guest code block for that the number of CPU cycles is known. The corresponding code is located here: https://github.com/maximumspatium/dingusppc/commit/11b4e99376e23f46f4cd8ee6223c5788ab963a37

While doing the above tests, I noticed that my MacBook Pro reports different numbers depending on CPU load. That is, when I run the above code with idle CPU I'm getting about 230000 ns execution time while with heavy-loaded CPU (neural net training, for example) I'm getting much better performance (< 70000 ns).

I suppose it's related to threads and scheduling in macOS. I'd like to utilize the full CPU power in my emulator. Is there a way to change thread performance to run at full speed, just like it does when the CPU is running under heavy load?

Thanks in advance!

P.S.: The machine in question is MacBook Pro 17´´ Mid 2010 with 2,53 GHz Intel Core i5 and 8GB RAM running MacOS 10.13.6.

Comment: "I'd like to utilize the full CPU power in my emulator. Is there a way to change thread performance to run at full speed, just like it does when the CPU is running under heavy load?"  Doesn't it run at full speed when under light load?

Comment: Power management is a big deal in laptop designs, users don't like the cooling fan to turn on. Only way to postpone that roar is to intentionally clock-down the processor. Until it can't be avoided anymore.  Google search results are too polluted by the thermal throttling issues discovered in the summer of last year to know what is supposed to happen.